# Is there a way to use shared_preferences with country_list_pick (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to save the option(the selected country) after the user closes the app.

this is the country picker code

```dart
 Center(
  child: CountryListPick(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      title: Text('Pick your country'),
    ),
    theme: CountryTheme(
      isShowFlag: true,
      isShowTitle: true,
      isShowCode: false,
      isDownIcon: true,
      showEnglishName: true,
    ),
    initialSelection: null,
    onChanged:(CountryCode code) {
      print(code.name);
      print(code.code);
      print(code.dialCode);
      print(code.flagUri);
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Could it be that you mean you want to have the previous selected option when the user restarts the app? It's not exactly the same as saving when the user closes. I think you should save the option when the user picks a country, because you're not really in control when the app is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shared_preferences` to save the country code when you select the country (as in @dumazy comment above - you don't know when an app will close, so saving the country code when selected is sensible).

```
Future<void> _saveCountry(String code) async {
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('country', code);
}

Future<String> _getSavedCountry() async {
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.getString('country');
}
```

You can then save the country code in the `onChanged` event...

```
                onChanged: (CountryCode code) async {
                  ...
                  await _saveCountry(code.code);
                }
```

Remember that `shared_preferences` reads and writes are asynchronous, so you will need to wrap your widget in a `FutureBuilder` to wait for the read to be completed.

```
return Center(
    child: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _getSavedCountry(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return CountryListPick(...
               initialSelection: snapshot.data,);
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        }));
```

Comment: I tried the code, but there was one problem which is when I open the app for the first time, the list box keeps loading, and I can't press on it,
 and there were no counties selected

Comment: `if (snapshot.hasData)` should be `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)`. If there is no saved_preference country, the snapshot will contain `null`, which is fine... except that hasData will remain as `false` :-)  Therefore use `connectionState` to determine that the future has completed.

Comment: Accepting the answer would be great, thanks